# JQuery UI Accordion dynamic creation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating dynamic accordions, for which i used a function as below

```
function buildAccordion(id,keys,values)
{
    var accord="<div id="+id+">";
    $.each(keys, function(i, value) 
    { 
        accord+="<h3><a href='#'>"+value+"</a></h3><div id="+values[i]+"></div>";
    });
    accord+="</div>";

    return accord;
}
```

`keys` is an array with accordion's header & `values` an array containing div id's (for adding content to each panel @ a later point of time)

Below is the function calling `buildAccordion` function

```
function alertsAccordion(id)
{
    var keys=   ["KB Alerts","Product Alerts","Emergency Bug Fix Alerts","Error Alerts"];
    var values= ["kbAlertsDiv","productAlertsDiv","ebfAlertsDiv","errorAlertsDiv"];

    var idd=id+"Panel";

    $('#divContent').empty();
    $('<div width="100%">')
    .attr('id','alertsSpan')
    .html('<div class="titleBlue">Alerts</div>'+buildAccordion(idd,keys,values)+'</div>')       
    .appendTo('#divContent').delay(1).queue(function(){
        $("#"+idd).accordion();     //So here I am triggering accordion
    });

    $("#kbAlertsDiv").html("Olha!");
    $("#productAlertsDiv").html("Guttentag!");
    $("#ebfAlertsDiv").html("Blah! blah!");
    $("#errorAlertsDiv").html("halo");
}
```

But the problem is the arrow icon & the header text for each panel is overlapped, What is the problem, am I doing something wrong?

Below is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Probably more of a CSS than a JavaScript issue, don't you think, try adding margin/padding to your `h3`s maybe?

Comment: @m90: Ya looks that way, but I have included `jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css` so it should not be a problem

Comment: Maybe your own CSS overrides some of the rules in the UI stylesheet, can you have a look at the computed properties your debugger gives you?

Comment: @m90: Thanks This is what i used, `<h3 style='padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px'>` your comment helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the css class `ui-accordion-header` to the h3 or div tag when you build it?